# Ordenar o queryset Django por prioridade

Tags: django, classificação, filter

Eu estou criando um sistema de buscas em minha plataforma. Eu faço uma busca pelo titulo do conteudo, descrição e tags dentro dele. Segue o código:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [(Q(name__icontains=word) | Q(description__icontains=word) | Q(tags__name__icontains=word)) for word in words]))
```

Dessa forma, eu consigo quebrar as palavras do texto e fazer uma busca bem bacana. O problema é, eu gostaria de ordenar por uma prioridade que eu criar, no caso, queria fazer na seguinte ordem:

1. Resultado exato
2. Resultado que começa com a palavra/frase
3. Resultado que termina com a palavra/frase
4. Resultado que contem na palavra/frase

Dessa forma eu vou exibir primeiro o resultado que é exatamente o que o usuario busca, depois resultados que começam com o que ele busca, terminam e que contém.

Porém com o meu código não consigo ver uma forma de fazer isso a não ser fazendo o **sql puro** usando **case when**.

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei uma solução mas não sei se é a melhor. Pra falar a verdade não deve ser já pelo fato de eu ter que **fazer 2 querys para trazer 1 lista**.

Eu crio 2 querysets, sendo a primeira para o match exato e a segunda para os possiveis matchs (como estou fazendo no exemplo que coloquei na pergunta). Segue o código:

```
from functools import reduce    

words = text.split()
q1 = Question.objects.filter(name__istartswith=text)[:1]
if q1.count() > 0:
    q1 = [q1[0]]
else:
    q1 = []

q2 = Question.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(name__icontains=word) for word in words]))[:4]
if q1:
    q2.exclude(id=q1[0].id)

if q2.count() > 0:
    q2 = [q for q in q2]
else:
    q2 = []

questions = list(q1) + list(q2)
```

No final ele me retorna os 5 resultados sendo o 1 o match perfeito.